# How do you make the music volume louder than the highest volume on the Sony Xperia M2

Tags: volume-control

I recently got a new phone and the music volume continues to decrease so I was wondering if there is a way to make the volume higher than the max volume on the Sony Xperia M2, also I have already put the sound enhancements on so I need a different way.

Comment: Have you checked [these questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=volume+boost+answers%3A1)? This question has already been asked multiple times here :) See e.g. [How can I increase the number of volume levels?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/46979/16575)

Comment: Has it been about music and for the Sony Xperia M2

Comment: What makes you thing adjusting volume has to be device- and sound- specific? Though we cannot generally rule-out device (or ROM) specific stuff, we can "rule it in" only using the Sherlock-Holmes-Algorithm: *When you have **excluded the impossible,** whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth.* So may I ask: Have you "excluded" – i.e. tried the other recommended solutions? :)

Comment: Yes, hence the question

Comment: Ah. In that case: could you please [edit] your question and point out what you've tried and how it failed (e.g. error messages / installation issues / no-effect-at-all / …) – so we might be able to narrow down things?

Comment: Ok. Do you have any suggestions on improvement

Comment: Yes. See my previous comment. I cannot do that for you – *you* must provide those details. And before we have them, I don't see how we can further assist you, sorry.

Comment: We? Or the general SE we

Comment: We. All. Everywhere. Except for those having your device in their own hands, literally. Our crystal balls are all out for maintenance currently – and we haven't been told when they will be returned.

Comment: I asked a question which could have been a straight answer yet you decide to use the extended, criticism filled method

Comment: Sorry, Joshua: I wrote multiple times we need more details to give a "straight answer". You never provided those details, so we cannot give that answer. Tell me: how far is it from my aunt Grace to the next bus stop? Can you answer that without me providing you with information on where she lives? // Count me out now, please. I tried to help as good as I could – but that was as far as I could go. Good luck!

Comment: Alright, fine. I'll edit or make a new post this is no democracy

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Volume Booster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.divi.volumebooster&hl=fr) app which increases maximum volume by 30-40%.

Alternatively, have a look at the Play Store search query [here](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=volume%20booster&c=apps&hl=fr). There are many other applications in Play Store which would meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

1. Root your phone.
2. Install [ViPER4Android Audio Effects](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2191223) app.
3. Click 'Yes' to install drivers.
   Select 'Super Audio Quality' in Preferences.
   Click 'Accept'.
4. Now reboot the phone and open the app.
5. Click the 3-dot option at top right to open options.
   Select UI Settings and enable 'Expert' mode.
6. Now in "Phone Speaker" tab, click 'Enable' under 'Master Power'.
7. Under 'Extra Loud'
   i. Enable it.
   ii.Select '**Effect Strength**' as '**Extreme**'
   iii. Select the '**Max Gain**' as required (recommended: 8x)