# How to increase/decrease volume in smaller increments/decrements?

Tags: huawei, volume-control

I'm using Huawei P10 (released in ~Feb 2017, using Android 7.0). One annoying thing I noticed is that the volume button changes the volume by 20 units (out of 100). Phone call volume in general is ok but for some apps like whatsapp, even 20 units is unbearably loud. I installed `Precise Volume` app which lets me change volume in smaller steps. However, it is not tied to the volume button i.e. I'd need to switch to that app's UI to change the volume. Is there any way to fix the volume button in general so that it changes the volume in smaller units?

I wonder if smartphone (software or hardware) makers are focusing too much on the `smart` and overlooking the basic `phone` features like call quality.

Comment: My bad, had posted a solution requiring Xposed not aware that Android 7 has no xposed framework (had to delete) though its the closest to what you're trying to achieve:(

Comment: @xavier_fakerat thanks for trying to help. i cannot believe that this simple volume thing is not supported despite all the `smart` bells and whistles in an android phone.

Answer (score 2):

From the look of things Android Nougat has limited options to achieve this, but still a few options exist:

**Using Magisk**

This method is belived to be ideal for devices running on Android 7.0+ Nougat as is in this case.

**Requirements**

- [Magisk](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.topjohnwu.magisk)
- [Terminal Emulator app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm).
- [Volume Steps Magisk module](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?w=files&flid=167933) (recent versions) or [XDA link](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/module-volume-steps-increase-magisk-v10-t3554996)

**Proceedure**

> 1. Install the module by flashing it via recovery or the Magisk Manager app;
> 2. Next, open the Terminal Emulator app and type this command: `vol_magisk`;
> 3. Press Enter;
> 4. If you used the latest version of the module, you would see some values that you can apply by typing and pressing enter.

---

*For other android (rooted) versions, please see the workaround in my other post : [How can I increase the number of volume levels?*](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/183332/209414)

**Edit**

For higher Magisk versions (20.4+) find the module [here](https://github.com/bladeSk/magisk-volume-steps/releases).The default config has media volume steps set to 30, call volume steps set to 10.

*However modifications can easily be made by customising `system.prop` values to your liking and zipping up the repo.*

Acknowledgements

- [Learn to Add More Steps to your Volume Slider with VolumeSteps+](http://androidflagship.com/25852-learn-to-add-more-steps-to-your-volume-slider-with-volumesteps)
- [Volume Steps Increase (for Magisk v10+)](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/module-volume-steps-increase-magisk-v10-t3554996)
- [bladeSk](https://github.com/bladeSk/magisk-volume-steps)